# c# send mail with smtp through exchange 2K7

Tags: c#, smtp, exchange-server

the following code works when sending through gmail's smtp but not through exchange 2K7.
on the same machine i have outlook express which does send through the exchange successfully.
i am using the same configurations in my code as in outlook express but keep getting the error:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.
The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated.
Stack:    at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send ...
```

Ssl is set to true.

here is da code:

```
//create new MailMessage
mailmessage = new MailMessage(definition.From, definition.To);
mailmessage.ReplyToList.Add(definition.From);
mailmessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailmessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mailmessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mailmessage.Subject = definition.Subject;
mailmessage.Body = definition.Body;

mailmessage = MessageBody.CompleteMessage(mailmessage, definition);

//send MailMessage
//get smtpclient
SmtpClient smtp = null;

if (smtp == null)
{
//create, init
smtp = new SmtpClient(definition.Server, definition.Port)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(definition.Uid, definition.Pwd),
    EnableSsl = definition.Ssl,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
};

}
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
smtp.Send(mailmessage);
```

UPDATE: when i take out the callback line and try to send i get this error:

```
Exception: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.. Stack:    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush()
   at System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
   at System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Comment: Just a guess:  The exchange server is using a self-signed cert.  You'll need install that cert on the machine running your code.

Comment: but does it make sense that outlook express would work on the same machine without the certificate installed? i thought it also uses SMTP.

Answer (score 3):

found a good solution. don't try to use smtp with exchange 2K7 and up. use EWS (Exchange Web Services) instead.

the steps are:

1. download the EWS managed API from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480
2. Install it
3. Add a reference to the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll to your project. you'll find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.1
4. Use the sample code below as a reference.

   using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

   using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

...

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

service.Url = new Uri(@"https://"+[Your exchange computer name like: abc.domain.com]+"/EWS/Exchange.asmx"); 

//if have the ip you can get the computer name using the nslookup utility in command line. ->nslookup 192.168.0.90 

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                    delegate(Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
                    {
                        return true;
                    };

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials([User name: either email or domain account-but without the domain\], "password");

EmailMessage mailmessage = new EmailMessage(service);

mailmessage.From="me@something.com";

mailmessage.ToRecipients.Add("someone@something.com");

mailmessage.Subject = "Hello";

mailmessage.Body = "World";

mailmessage.Body.BodyType = BodyType.HTML; //or text

mailmessage.Send();
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff, it looks like you are doing everything correctly. The two suggestions I have are stabs in the dark, but something you may want to look closer at:

Since you are getting: `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated. Stack: at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand ...`  I'm going to have to assume that the Exchange server is having a problem interpreting the packet it is receiving.

1) This could be due to SSL encryption. I would double-check that you need SSL. You can send (although it is not recommended) the username and password without SSL. It would be a poor server setup, but that's probably beyond your control.

2) You're also doing a certificate validation callback. That is an extra layer of SMTP validation that may be conflicting with he SSL packet. Can you send the mail without that line?

I hope these can push you in a direction to the TRUE answer.

Comment: tried no SSL.. no joy. its set up to require SSL. will try # 2.

Comment: took out that line. see UPDATE in the post.